# Fileupload image to library

Tags: development, sharepoint-designer

i want to use an List that i create by me self that named MyList that done! Then on my webpart i want to use Fileupload to upload an picture to MyList, is it possible?
Then for showing it on my page i want to use an Image control,
Someone that know were to start?

My Code looks as following when saving to the list
But here i am using Attachment

```
            SPSite site = new SPSite("http://wingtip") ;

            SPWeb web = SPContext.Current.Web;
            SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("MyList");




            try
            {
                if (list != null)


                {

                    SPListItem item = list.Items.Add();

                    if (TextBox_Name.Text==string.Empty&&TextBox_ProdNum.Text==string.Empty&&TextBox_ListPrice.Text==string.Empty&&TextBox_Color.Text==string.Empty&&TextBox_MoreInfo.Text==string.Empty)
                    {
                        Label1.Text = "Error:No Entered Value!´";
                        Label1.Visible = false;


                    }
                    else
                    {

                        item["Name"] = TextBox_Name.Text;

                        item["ProductNumber"] = TextBox_ProdNum.Text;

                        item["ListPrice"] = TextBox_ListPrice.Text;

                        item["Color"] = TextBox_Color.Text;

                        item["More Info"] = TextBox_MoreInfo.Text;


                        if (FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile != null && FileUpload_Pic.HasFile)
                        {
                            Stream fStream = FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.InputStream;

                            byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
                            fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
                            fStream.Close();
                            fStream.Dispose();

                            SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload_Pic.PostedFile.FileName);
                            attachments.Add(fileName, contents);

                            //listItem["Attached FileName"] = fileName; // store the name of the file in a column for future requirements
                            item.Update();
                        }

                        if (FileUpload_Doc.PostedFile != null && FileUpload_Doc.HasFile)
                        {
                            Stream fStream = FileUpload_Doc.PostedFile.InputStream;

                            byte[] contents = new byte[fStream.Length];
                            fStream.Read(contents, 0, (int)fStream.Length);
                            fStream.Close();
                            fStream.Dispose();

                            SPAttachmentCollection attachments = item.Attachments;
                            string fileName = Path.GetFileName(FileUpload_Doc.PostedFile.FileName);
                            attachments.Add(fileName, contents);




                        }



                        item.Update();


                        //Rensar texboxarna


                        TextBox_Name.Text = string.Empty;

                        TextBox_ProdNum.Text = string.Empty;

                        TextBox_ListPrice.Text = string.Empty;

                        TextBox_Color.Text = string.Empty;

                        TextBox_MoreInfo.Text = string.Empty;

                        TextBox_Search.Text = string.Empty;


                        site.Dispose();

                    }

                    }



            }


    catch (Exception )
    {


        Label1.Text = "Error:No Entered Value!";
    }
```

Comment: What is the problem with this code? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: Hi! No! But i would like to show my picture on an image control also on my webpart in my content...

Answer (score 0):

First you need to get the url for the list itself.  The url for the list is simply:

```
string listUrl = web.Url + "/" + list.RootFolder.Url;
```

Then, you use the list url, the item id and the attachment name to construct the whole attachment url.  The completed url is:

```
string attachmentUrl;
if (listItem.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
    string filename = listItem.Attachments[0];
    attachmentUrl = listUrl + "/attachments/" + item.ID + "/" + filename;
}
```

Once you have the URL, you can simply use this in Image Control:

```
Image1.ImageUrl = attachmentUrl;
```

Ref: [Getting the Url for an SPListItem’s Attachment](http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=61)

Comment: hi Image1.ImageUrl = attachmentUrl; i wrote this in my selecteditem button from my listbox but attachmentUrl gets red

Comment: under my textboxes that i have posted before , wrote ,

Comment: string listUrl = web.Url + "http://wingtip" + list.RootFolder.Url;

                            if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
                            {
                                string filename = item.Attachments[0];
                                string attachmentUrl = listUrl + "/Attachments/" + item.ID + "http://wingtip" + filename;
                                
                            }

Comment: Updated the answer

Comment: it will help if u can answer my question

Comment: What you understood by the answer I have posted ?? Did you tried that ??

Comment: yes nothing didnt work

Comment: didn't work doesn't give any explanation, learn something from Kristian! What errors do you receive, are their any run-time exceptions ?